# How to handle Download blocked pop up in selenium Java?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Here is the Pop up
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24STp.png)

How to handle this and click on Keep.

I have tried

```
options.addArguments("--safebrowsing-disable-download-protection"); 
options.addArguments("safebrowsing-disable-extension-blacklist");
Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<>();
prefs.put("download.default_directory", downloadDirectory);
prefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
```

But not working.